# Задать цвет с помощью R, G, B составляющих

Tags: c++, sfml

В документации написано:

```
Detailed Description

Utility class for manpulating RGBA colors.

sf::Color is a simple color class composed of 4 components:

Red
Green
Blue
Alpha (opacity)
Each component is a public member, an unsigned integer in the range [0, 255]. Thus, colors can be constructed and manipulated very easily:

sf::Color color(255, 0, 0); // red
color.r = 0;                // make it black
color.b = 128;              // make it dark blue
```

[Ссылка...]
[1]
Но почему тогда компилятор указывает на ошибки при задании цвета BACKGROUND?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;


constexpr unsigned BALLS_COUNT = 4;
const string WINDOW_TITLE = "Moving balls";
static const sf::Color BACKGROUND_COLOR;// = sf::Color(255, 255, 255);
BACKGROUND_COLOR.red = 255;
BACKGROUND_COLOR.g = 255;
BACKGROUND_COLOR.b = 255;
constexpr unsigned WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
constexpr unsigned WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

struct Colr
{
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;

    bool operator<(const Colr& curr) const
    {
        if (red < curr.red)
        {
           return true;
        }
        else if (red == curr.red)
        {
            if (green < curr.green)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (green == curr.green)
            {
                return blue < curr.blue;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};

struct Ball
{
    CircleShape shape;
    Vector2f offset;
};

struct PRNG
{
    std::mt19937 engine;
};

void initGenerator(PRNG& generator)
{
    // Используем время с 1 января 1970 года в секундах как случайное зерно
    const unsigned seed = unsigned(std::time(nullptr));
    generator.engine.seed(seed);
    cout << "seed == " << seed << endl;
}

// Генерирует индекс в диапазоне [0, size)
size_t random_index(PRNG& generator, int size)
{
    // Создаём распределение
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, size - 1);

    // Вычисляем псевдослучайное число: вызовем распределение как функцию,
    //  передав генератор произвольных целых чисел как аргумент.
    return distribution(generator.engine);
}

Colr initColor(PRNG generator, set<Colr>& isColrs)
{
    Colr colr;
    colr.red = random_index(generator, 256);
    colr.green = random_index(generator, 256);
    colr.blue = random_index(generator, 256);
    if(isColrs.empty() || (isColrs.find(colr) == isColrs.end()))
    {
        isColrs.insert(colr);
        return colr;
    }
    else
    {
        initColor(generator, isColrs);        
    }
}

void pollEvents(RenderWindow& window)
{
    Event event{};
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case Event::Closed:
            window.close();
            break;
        default:
            break;  
        }
    }
}

float length(const Vector2f& value)
{
    return std::hypot(value.x, value.y);
}

float distance(const Ball& ball, const Ball& curr)
{
    return length(ball.shape.getPosition() - curr.shape.getPosition());
}

float dot(const Vector2f& left, const Vector2f& right)
{
    return left.x * right.x + left.y * right.y;
}

float sqr(float value)
{
    return value * value;
}

sf::Vector2f getSpeedAfterStrike(const Ball& first, const Ball& second)
{
    const Vector2f deltaSpeed = first.offset - second.offset;
    const Vector2f deltaPos = first.shape.getPosition() - second.shape.getPosition();
    return first.offset - deltaPos * (dot(deltaSpeed, deltaPos) / sqr(length(deltaPos)));
}

void update(vector<Ball>& balls, float deltaTime)
{
    constexpr float MAX_DELTA_TIME = 0.1f;
    deltaTime = std::min(deltaTime, MAX_DELTA_TIME);

    for (auto& ball: balls)
    {
        if ((ball.shape.getPosition().x + ball.shape.getRadius() >= WINDOW_WIDTH) || (ball.shape.getPosition().y + ball.shape.getRadius() >= WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        || (ball.shape.getPosition().x - ball.shape.getRadius() <= 0) || (ball.shape.getPosition().y - ball.shape.getRadius() <= 0))
        {
            ball.offset = -ball.offset;
        }
    }

    for (size_t fi = 0; fi < balls.size(); ++fi)
    {
        for (size_t si = fi + 1; si < balls.size(); ++si)
        {
            Ball& first = balls[fi];
            Ball& second = balls[si];
            if (distance(first, second) <= (first.shape.getRadius() + second.shape.getRadius()))
            {
                const Vector2f newFirstSpeed = getSpeedAfterStrike(first, second);
                const Vector2f newSecondSpeed = getSpeedAfterStrike(second, first);
                first.offset = newFirstSpeed;
                second.offset = newSecondSpeed;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto& ball: balls)
    {
        ball.shape.move(ball.offset * deltaTime);
    }
}

void redrawFrame(RenderWindow& window, vector<Ball>& balls)
{
    window.clear(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    for (auto& ball: balls)
    {
        window.draw(ball.shape);        
    }
    window.display();
}

void initBall(PRNG generator, vector<Ball>& balls, Ball& ball, set<Colr>& isColrs)
{
    const vector<float> sizes = {
        40,
        40,
        40,
        40
    };    

    const vector<Vector2f> positions = {
        { 5* sizes.at(0), 5 * sizes.at(0) },
        { WINDOW_WIDTH - 3 * sizes.at(1), WINDOW_HEIGHT - 12 * sizes.at(1) },
        { WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2 },
        { WINDOW_WIDTH - 3 * sizes.at(3), WINDOW_HEIGHT - 3 * sizes.at(3) }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < BALLS_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        balls.at(i).offset.x = random_index(generator, 250);
        balls.at(i).offset.y = random_index(generator, 250);
        balls.at(i).shape.setRadius(sizes.at(i));
        balls.at(i).shape.setPosition(positions.at(i));
        Colr colr = initColor(generator, isColrs);
        balls.at(i).shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(colr.red, colr.green, colr.blue));
        balls.at(i).shape.setOrigin(balls.at(i).shape.getRadius(), balls.at(i).shape.getRadius());
    }
}

void init(PRNG& generator, set<Colr>& isColrs, vector<Ball>& balls, Ball& ball)
{
    initGenerator(generator);
    initBall(generator, balls, ball, isColrs);
}

int main()
{
    Clock clock;
    ContextSettings settings;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode({WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT}), WINDOW_TITLE, Style::Default, settings);
    vector<Ball> balls(BALLS_COUNT);
    PRNG generator;
    Ball ball;
    set<Colr> isColrs; 

    init(generator, isColrs, balls, ball);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        float deltaTime = clock.restart().asSeconds();
        pollEvents(window);
        update(balls, deltaTime);
        redrawFrame(window, balls);
    }
}
```

Ошибки компилятора:

```
 [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/workshop2.4.dir/main.obj
    D:\cpp\Projects\labs\workshop2\workshop2.4\main.cpp:20:1: error: 'BACKGROUND_COLOR' does not name a type
     BACKGROUND_COLOR.red = 255;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    D:\cpp\Projects\labs\workshop2\workshop2.4\main.cpp:21:1: error: 'BACKGROUND_COLOR' does not name a type
     BACKGROUND_COLOR.g = 255;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    D:\cpp\Projects\labs\workshop2\workshop2.4\main.cpp:22:1: error: 'BACKGROUND_COLOR' does not name a type
     BACKGROUND_COLOR.b = 255;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\workshop2.4.dir\build.make:63: CMakeFiles/workshop2.4.dir/main.obj] Error 1
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/workshop2.4.dir/all] Error 2
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:83: all] Error 2
```

Comment: На какую строчку ругается и что пишет. Полный текст ошибки добавь.

Comment: компилятор ругается на строчки: BACKGROUND_COLOR.red = 255;
BACKGROUND_COLOR.green = 255;
BACKGROUND_COLOR.blue = 255;

Comment: Подозреваю, что у вас там поля `.r`, а не `.red`, ну, и так далее. В описании же указано `color.r = 0;`. Почему вы закомментировали это - `//BACKGROUND_COLOR.r = 255;`? С ним не работало?

Comment: нет. одна и та же ошибка в обоих случаях.

Comment: @deekee, хотите чтоб помогли, тогда скопируйте сюда сообщение об ошибке, которое выдает компилятор. Тут не конкур изложения с элементами сочинения, а телепатов нет. Должно быть что-то `source_file.cpp(12): error C2039: 'x': is not a member of 'A'
source_file.cpp(6): note: see declaration of 'A'` или `source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:7:5: error: ‘X’ was not declared in this scope
     X a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static const sf::Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = sf::Color(255, 255, 255);
//BACKGROUND_COLOR.red = 255; // Так можно писать только внутри функции
//BACKGROUND_COLOR.g = 255;   // В глобальном пространстве нельзя
//BACKGROUND_COLOR.b = 255; 
constexpr unsigned WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
```

Чем вариант ниже не устраивал?

```
static const sf::Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = sf::Color(255, 255, 255);
```

Comment: хотел использовать в программе сравнение с каждой составляющей  BACKGROUND_COLOR, но кажется обошел этот момент. Так что вопрос можно считать закрытым